# in SQL, how to remove distinct column values (not rows, as usually done)

Tags: sql, distinct, presto

I have a production case, for a supply chain. We have devices that are moved around in warehouses, and I need to find the previous warehouse locations.

I have a table like this:

```
+--------+------------+--------+--------+--------+
| device | current_WH | prev_1 | prev_2 | prev_3 |
+--------+------------+--------+--------+--------+
|      1 | AB         | KK     | KK     | KK     |
|      2 | DE         | DE     | DE     | NQ     |
|      3 | FF         | MM     | ST     | ST     |
+--------+------------+--------+--------+--------+
```

I need to find the distinct values of current_WH and the "prev" columns. So I'm not flattening rows, but narrowing columns. I need to get this:

```
+--------+------------+--------+--------+--------+
| device | current_WH | prev_1 | prev_2 | prev_3 |
+--------+------------+--------+--------+--------+
|      1 | AB         | KK     | blank  | blank  |
|      2 | DE         | NQ     | blank  | blank  |
|      3 | FF         | MM     | ST     | blank  |
+--------+------------+--------+--------+--------+
```

I'll figure out nulls or blanks later. But for now I need one row for each device that shows the current WH and previous locations. There could be any number - not always the same.

If I do "distinct" that flattens rows. Doing a distinct and group by doesn't achieve the requirement.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to update the table or merely select data differently?

Comment: Columns and rows are *very different things* in SQL. This isn't a spreadsheet. If you've got multiple columns containing the same "type" of data, it's a pointer to bad data modelling in the first place.

Comment: what if device has next row(current, p1,p2,p3): `AB, CD, AB, CD`, what should be returned?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner, I am not updating the table. So I can select and rename columns in anyway.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, this is a simplified version of what it looks like in production. The real case has many rows for each device, with timestamps. I used dense_rank (partition by device order by date) to get this output. I could alter the approach if needed.

Comment: Wait, "I used dense_rank [..] to get this output" - does this mean the table you are showing is not a database table, but a query result?

Comment: The production table looks more like this. You can see the rank column which goes by date. 

+--------+------------+-----------+------+
| device | current_WH |   date    | rank |
+--------+------------+-----------+------+
|      1 | BB         | 5/11/2018 |    3 |
|      1 | BB         | 5/11/2018 |    3 |
|      1 | BB         | 5/15/2018 |    2 |
|      1 | BB         | 5/15/2018 |    2 |
|      1 | AA         | 6/6/2018  |    1 |
|      1 | AA         | 6/6/2018  |    1 |
+--------+------------+-----------+------+

Comment: **[edit]** your question to add this sort of detail. It's unreadable in the comments.

Comment: I have posted a new question because I can't seem to make the table readable in a comment (no markdown). Thanks. 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51877617/sql-how-to-get-unique-values-in-a-column-distinct-does-not-help-here

Answer (score 1):

You need to do unpivot to let your column value rows, because that will easier to compare before `current_WH` value data, then do a pivot to recover the data schema.

1. Do *unpivot* to let your column value rows, because that will easier to compare before `current_WH` value data, and add a new `grp` column it can help to recover your expected result.
2. use `LAG` function to get the previous value it will be compared with `current_WH` value.
3. use `SUM` with `CASE WHEN` and *window function* to cumulative number if the previous equal to `current_WH` value.
4. if the `SUM` cumulative number greater than `0` means the name was repeated.

look like this.

```
with cteUnion as( 
    SELECT device,current_WH,0 grp
    FROM T
    UNION ALL
    SELECT device,prev_1,1 grp
    FROM T
    UNION ALL
    SELECT device,prev_2,2 grp
    FROM T
    UNION ALL
    SELECT device,prev_3,3 grp
    FROM T
),cte1 as(
  SELECT *,
         LAG(current_WH) over(partition by current_WH order by grp) perviosVal
   from cteUnion
),cteResult as (
  SELECT *,
        (CASE WHEN sum(CASE WHEN perviosVal = current_WH  then 1 else 0 end) over(partition by device order by grp) > 0 THEN 'Block' else current_WH end) val
  FROM cte1
)

select device,
      MAX(CASE WHEN grp = 0 then val end) current_WH ,
      MAX(CASE WHEN grp = 1 then val end) prev_1,
      MAX(CASE WHEN grp = 2 then val end) prev_2,
      MAX(CASE WHEN grp = 3 then val end) prev_3
from cteResult
GROUP BY device
```

[sqlfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/uxEoKSLVpvnhg8n3MtyrqZ/1)

**NOTE**

`grp` column number value depends on your order.